# How do you add external libraries to 'self-made' libraries using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, include, file-not-found, cmakelists-options

I'm not able to link external libraries with the libraries I wrote using CMake. I'm wondering if there's something that is needed to be added to my `CMakeLists.txt`? Or if I need to add another `CMakeLists.txt` in a lower level (inside `src`) and what would that need to contain?

I have the following project structure:

```
ProjectFolder
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── build
│   │   └── 
│   ├── include
│   │   └── helper.h
│   └── src
│       ├── helper.cpp
        └── main.cpp
```

My `CMakeList.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(object_detection)

find_package(PCL 1.5 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)


file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB INCLUDE include/*.h)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${INCLUDE})
link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${SOURCES} )
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})


add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME}  ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${SOURCES})
```

In my file `helper.cpp` I have:

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
```

Which gives the error:

```
fatal error: 'pcl/io/pcd_io.h' file not found
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However I have the same include in `main.cpp` with no errors.

I would be very grateful for any help, please let me know if I need to clarify my question or error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in the `CMakeLists.txt` with the following changes the project loads appropriate libraries and builds properly. Another note is that before, to include `helper.h` I needed to write:
`#include "../include/helper.h"`.
Now it works as expected with `#include "helper.h"`.
Here is the modified CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(object_detection)

find_package(PCL 1.5 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)


file(GLOB SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)


include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)
link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})


#add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} src/helper.cpp src/main.cpp )
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES} )

target_link_libraries (object_detection ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```